# Force StarTeam to checkout files with read and write permissions?

Tags: starteam

Under "Personal Options", I have the option "Mark unlocked working files read-only" unchecked. Yet, every-time I checkout a file (without locking it), the file is read-only in my working directory. I assume that this due to a server policy. Is there anyway to overwrite that policy?

Comment: Why was this question closed? It's about source control and that's "software tools commonly used by programmers" as indicated in the faq.

Comment: Agreed. I've nominated it for reopening, but others will have to vote to reopen for that to happen.

Answer (score 2):

In the Project properties in the StarTeam cross-platform client, under the "Options" tab there is also a "Mark unlocked working files read-only". That may be overriding your personal setting.

Comment: You are correct Slapout. The Project is indeed configured this way and I do not have the access rights to modify it. Can you foce the personal settings in any way?

Comment: I don't think you can. You will probably have to talk to your StarTeam admin and see if they would be willing to change it for you.